# Is mean of rolling window R2 is the total R2 of regression?

Tags: python, r, statistics, regression, data-science

Quick Quesiton here.

I have to calculate the mean of a 60 days rolling window R2 time serie. My time serie has 4680 observations.

I was wondering, is the mean of the serie of R2 the total R2 of the regression?

Example :

Mean(series of r2) = R2 of the regression on all the sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try it.  We show two equivalent ways to define R squared in this context:

```
library(zoo)
set.seed(123)
n <- 4680
w <- 60
x <- rnorm(4680)

r2 <- function(x) summary(lm(x ~ seq_along(x)))$r.squared
# r2 <- function(x) cor(x, seq_along(x))^2  # this is equivalent

mean(rollapplyr(x, w, r2))
## [1] 0.4992133

r2(x)
## [1] 0.0001151601
```